# Displaying Data without *Ngfor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display data without using a `ngFor` loop. It works perfectly but shows all of the quote information from multiple customers. The CSS is laid out in a way that has the discount div next to the `customerinfo` div Here is the HTML

```html
<hr />
<div class="info">
    <div id="CustomerInfoInline" *ngIf="quotes" >
        <div *ngFor="let q of quotes">
            <h6>Name: {{q.firstName}} {{q.lastName}}</h6>
            <h6>Address: {{q.address}}</h6>
            <h6>City, State, Zip: {{q.city}}, {{q.state}}, {{q.zip}}</h6>
            <h6>SSN: {{q.SSN}}</h6>
            <h6>DOB: {{q.dateOfBirth}}</h6>
            <h6>Email: {{q.email}}</h6>
            <h6>Prev. Carrier: {{q.previousCarrier}}</h6>
            <h1>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="quotes">
        <div id="CustomerDiscountsInline" *ngFor="let q of quotes">
            <h6 id="customerBold">Customer Discounts</h6>
            <h4 id="DiscountsID">discounts will be applied here</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

and the respective TS

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { Quote } from '@app/_models/quote';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quote-summary',
  templateUrl: './quote-summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quote-summary.component.css']
})
export class QuoteSummaryComponent implements OnInit {

    apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl
    quotes: Quote[]
    //TODO: implement submitted quote view later
    //submittedQuotes: Quote[]

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
 
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getQuotes()
    }
    // #region API Calls

    getQuotes() {
        var httpRequest = this.http.get<Quote[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/quotes`)

        httpRequest.subscribe(returnedQuotes => {
            this.quotes = returnedQuotes
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish / do? Why not use an `*ngFor` or what problems does `*ngFor` give you that you want to do something else?

Comment: @Igor I'm trying to display info for just one customer. So first name thru email. But not display the same info but for the next customer. It's showing multiple CustomerInfoInline divs

Comment: You mean `<h6>Name: {{quotes[0].firstName}} {{quotes[0].lastName}}</h6>`?

Comment: You could use a normal indexer on the array. You could also create a field in the component that points to one customer and then reference that. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Exactly! How would i be able to do that with dynamic indexes. For example index 2 gets passed through and it would put in {{quotes[2].firstname}}

Comment: Use a field in the component and then replace 2 with that field. Same way you would in normal javascript.

Comment: I agree with @Igor just you need to define an number variable (say `indexer`) in your component and then in your html would be look like: `quotes[indexer].firstname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show only one customer you can use indexer for `quotes` like `quotes[0]`:

Don't forgot to check `quotes.length > 0`:

```
<div class="info">
    <div id="CustomerInfoInline" 
        <div *ngIf="quotes && quotes.length > 0">
            <h6>Name: {{quotes[0].firstName}} {{quotes[0].lastName}}</h6>
            <h6>Address: {{quotes[0].address}}</h6>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @John Has your problem been solved? if you need to use dynamic index just create a number variable in your component and use it instead of constant index like: `quotes[indexer].firstname`